# Is there an event fired when WebBrowser content is redrawn?

Tags: c#

I'm using a WebBrowser control, and at a certain point I update the style of an  element with, for instance: `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementId").Style = "color: red";`

The WebBrowser control is automatically redrawn to reflect the changed style, but the DocumentCompleted event does not fire.
Is there an event that fires in this case?

Comment: Why do you need such event?

Comment: There's no event for this.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the WinForms `WebBrowser` control does not provide such an event.
But the control is really mighty, so with some tricks you can implement your desired behaviour: You already discovered, that you can access the DOM tree via the `Document` property, but you can also communicate with scripts running in the WebBrowser via both the `ObjectForScripting` property and the method `Document.InvokeScript`. Since 'Vanilla' Javascript can listen to DOM tree changes, you can create a script, which registers for such changes and route them to the application that hosts your `WebBrowser` control.

The small class below is just an example how this could work, of course you can alter the Javascript listener to receive more specialized events.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class DOMListener
{
    public event Action DOMChanged;

    private WebBrowser Browser;

    public DOMListener(WebBrowser webbrowser)
    {
        this.Browser = webbrowser;
        this.Browser.ObjectForScripting = this;
        this.Browser.DocumentCompleted += OnDOMLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDOMLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement script = this.Browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
        script.InnerHtml = "function listenToDOM() { document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) { window.external.DOMUpdate() }); }";
        this.Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].AppendChild(script);
        this.Browser.Document.InvokeScript("listenToDOM");
    }

    public void DOMUpdate()
    {
        if (this.DOMChanged != null) this.DOMChanged.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Just create an instance of this class with your WebBrowser as argument and you will be able to receive DOM tree changes via the `DOMChanged` event:

```
private DOMListener Listener;

public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Listener = new DOMListener(this.WebBrowser);
    this.Listener.DOMChanged += this.OnDOMChanged;
    this.WebBrowser.Navigate("www.google.de");
}

void OnDOMChanged()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": DOM changed");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, lukegv, I will try this approach.